# Semi transparent modal view controller does not cover status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've got a semi transparent view controller presented modally. But it doesn't cover status bar, so it looks like this

[image]

I want to know if there is any way to make status bar darkened too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a UINavigationController then you can adjust the contents of the Status Bar using UIBarStyle of the UINavigationBar.
 And in case you have not further information can be found in this article:
https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/